# Firebase cloud function POST HTTPS Request from ESP8266

Tags: firebase, https, google-cloud-functions, esp8266, arduino-ide

I want to connect to an url of a cloud function but isn´t working. someone can see the error? I´m working with an ESP8266 from arduino IDE. I try sending a POST request by postman and it function perfectly, I don´t understan what is the problem with the conection, i always try to connect with out the https and only with http and again in the esp8266 didn´t wotk but in postman does works fine, I do not understant why is this problem

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>


const char* ssid     = "My wifi";
const char* password = "My Password";

const char* host = "https://us-central1-sensores4bad6.cloudfunctions.net/actualizar";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

int value = 0;

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
  ++value;

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  WiFiClientSecure client;
  const int httpPort = 443;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
     Serial.println("connection failed");
     return;
  }



 client.print(String("POST ") + host + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }
  while (client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

Comment: In the example https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/HTTPSRequest/HTTPSRequest.ino the host string does not contain the protocol.

Comment: All Google web endpoints, including those in Cloud Functions, require https and do no support plain http.

Comment: You can't just stuff the full URL everywhere and expect it to work.

Comment: I try it without the "https://" in the url and is the same resault it says conecction failed, but in postman i can do a post with "https://" and with out protocol in the uRL

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `s` in `https`. So:

```c
const char* host = "http://us-central1-sensores4bad6.cloudfunctions.net/actualizar";
```

instead of

```c
const char* host = "https://us-central1-sensores4bad6.cloudfunctions.net/actualizar";
```